# How to call events in different event handlers?

Tags: c#

How to call `DataGrideEventHandler`  `ColumnHeaderMouseClick`
in  `dataGridView_ColumnWidthChanged` event handler?

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender,
                                                  DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
        //some code
}

private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender,e);//its not working
}
```

Comment: Move the code inside your event handler into another method.  Call that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this (because it tends to become spaghetti code), then you can pass null to the ColumneHeaderMouseClick like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender,
                                                  DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
        //some code, but do not rely on e != null
}

private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender, null);
}
```

But I recomment to extract as much code as possible from the event handler to some other classes in order to avoid tight coupling in UI code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this to trigger the event:

```
dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(new object(), null);
```

The reason why your code isn't working because you're trying to pass a different type. You were passing `DataGridViewColumnEventArgs` instead of `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks ,you are right, there is different type of eventArgs , your code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are have different signatures, same `sender` but different `EventArgs`. So you need rewrite `EventArgs` again.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var margs = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons, 1, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 0);
    var args = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(e.Column.Index, 0, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, margs);
    dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender, args);
}
```